# Problem with php storm configuration, CS Fixer Code Sniffer Mess Detector

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

I've tried to configure my PHP storm with all that stuff. I have positive feedback about validations. Also in inspection looks properly, but I constantly get an error of status 500.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems like PHP storm have a problem with coding standards, but in container, everything is fine and packages works as they should

Comment: Alrght so, the thing was that the Docker won't share all necessary files. In that case, I'll recommend sharing the whole C drive in docker. No one has helped me with that, but hopefully someone find a solution of his problem in here :))